# Нужны ли кавычки в диалоге?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, диалог

***— Он опять это сделал.***

***— В смысле («)опять(»)?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• Чуть-чуть правил ([Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160)):

> **5.** Если в последующей реплике повторяются слова из предыдущей реплики, принадлежащей другому лицу, причем они воспринимаются как чужой текст, то эти слова выделяются кавычками:
> а) Купавина. *Ах, это смешно наконец. Зачем юристом, когда ничего нет.*
> Лыняев. *Как «ничего»?*
> Купавина. *Так, ничего, чистая бумага* (Остр.)...

• Немного о значении:
при постановке вопроса сочетание *в смысле* используется в качестве наречия. В этом случае оно имеет значение "зачем?", "с какой стати?, "почему?".

• Я бы **поставила кавычки**:

*— Он опять это сделал.

— В смысле «опять»?* [Что значит «опять»?]

• А еще можно дополнительно поставить тире — для обозначения паузы от удивления или растерянности.

*— Он опять это сделал.

— В смысле — «опять»?*